# Why is my node.js application having issues when deployed on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, port

I am having the below issue when I deployed my application to Heroku. The application is working fine locally but on deployment to Heroku, it is giving the below error

**2023-08-21T05:30:24.694959+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=decode-project-1ce46d29e037.herokuapp.com request_id=8e9ac001-e8de-4474-b149-d0b312234b44 fwd="154.120.116.248" dyno= connect=
service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https**

Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

Note: The above is my log which I accessed with "heroku log"

Also, below is my index file for the PORT

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import cors from 'cors';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

import postRoutes from './routes/posts.js';

const app= express();
dotenv.config();


app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: "30mb", extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: "30mb", extended: true}));
app.use(cors());
app.use('/posts', postRoutes);

app.get('/', (req, res) =>{
    res.send('Hello to Decode API');
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, '0.0.0.0', () => console.log(`Server is runing at Port ${PORT}`));

mongoose.connect(process.env.CONNECTION_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

//mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
```

Comment: The problem persist. I listen to the port first before I execute my mongoose API but the problem persist

Comment: Can you update your code to: `app.listen(PORT, '0.0.0.0', () => console.log('server')` and check if it works?

Comment: Do you mean I should update my whitelisted IP address on mongodb to 0.0.0.0

Comment: No, it's related to heroku (and not `mongodb`). Remove all your `mongoose` code first. See whether answer works in heroku.

Comment: heroku has logged my account out, saying "my session has expired". Also I cannot register on heroku with a valid email address and that's why I made use of a temp email

Comment: But does my answer work for you (with the new heroku account)? if not, can you update the question with the latest code so that I can see what's the issue?

Comment: The chody.com domain for getting temp mail has been blocked from heroku. I dont know how to create a new account. Pls can you help me

Comment: What happened to your original heroku account? `my session has expired` means login again.

Comment: Like the account was deleted from their database. Now I'm seeing "couldn't find that user" when I want to login again

Comment: No update, i left heroku. I don't know if they don't allow Nigerians to register on it

Comment: If its ok with you, can you accept my answer then?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your `app.listen` call to:

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, '0.0.0.0', () => {
  console.log('Server is running');
})
```

> In rarer cases, your app may be using process.env.PORT, but may still be failing to bind. This can be caused by the app attempting to bind on localhost. Instead, you may need to change this to 0.0.0.0.
>
> https://help.heroku.com/P1AVPANS/why-is-my-node-js-app-crashing-with-an-r10-error